# Factoring question on binomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm trying to reduce the following expression.  The steps follow an online CAS and I have a question regarding a step.

$= (b-1)(\frac {1-b^n} {1-b})$

$= \frac {(1-b^n)(b-1)} {1-b}$

The next steps indicates cancellation.  Does anyone know what is being canceled?

$= -(-b^n + 1) = b^n - 1$

Comment: $(b-1) = (-1)\times (1-b)$

Answer (score 1):

I have put the cancelled parts in boldface so you can see them.

$$(b-1)\left(\frac {1-b^n} {1-b}\right)
=\frac{(b-1)(1-b^n)}{1-b}
=\frac{\mathbf{(b-1)}(1-b^n)}{-\mathbf{(b-1)}}=\frac{(1-b^n)}{-1}=(b^n-1)$$